# How to get the Adaptec 1200A to work under Linux at UDMA/100 (instead of 66)

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, hardware, pci

A while ago, I got myself a used Adaptec 1200A controller card to keep my onboard slots free for easier connect/disconnect of drives and now I am wondering why this card will only operate at **UDMA 66**.

However. I am not going to accept a response like "this is an old card, you can't expect it to go higher than that". This is not true, as the original hardware was *definitely* sold as a UDMA/100-capable one. [Older screenshots](http://lnx.gtirn.com/images/immagini_vendita/adaptec_1200A_bundle.jpg) of the original box that I found in the net after some research have proved this fact, too.

When I asked someone else about this, he told me it may be that I am using the "wrong driver". Well, I just let the kernel do the initialization work, and this is the result from `dmesg`/`syslog`:

```
ata5: PATA max UDMA/66 cmd 0x (...)
```

See also:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=610627

Output of `lspci -knn`:

```
01:09.0 Mass storage controller [0180]: HighPoint Technologies, Inc. HPT366/368/370/370A/372/372N [1103:0004] (rev 03)
Subsystem: HighPoint Technologies, Inc. HPT370 UDMA100 [1103:0005]
```

So yes, this chip is definitely UDMA/100 capable. Just the driver prevents it.

Comment: Have you verified that your disks are UDMA/100, and that the cable is rated for UDMA/100? (If you have two disks on the same cable, it will default to the slower speed on both disks.) Also, even if your cable is rated for 100, you might try another cable.

Comment: Yes, of course! With another non-Adaptec card, these disks *do* perform at UDMA/100 speed (or even higher, occasionally). Only whenever they're connected to the 1200A, they're recognized as UDMA/66 because the kernel "thinks" this card is only UDMA/66 hardware (which it definitely isn't). Plus, all my drives that could really only do UDMA/66 (max) were binned a long time ago. :) (Since they would act as system brakes, as you correctly pointed out)

Comment: Could you post your kernel's boot logs? Typically they'll be in `/var/log/dmesg`; there might be some more information on how the kernel is initialising your 1200A.

Comment: Frankly? I doubt it! This is __all__ you will ever get from the `dmesg` log: `ata5: PATA max UDMA/66 cmd 0x(hexaddr) ctl 0x(hexaddr) bmdma 0x(
hexaddr) irq xx`. -- That one lone line really won't help much, otherwise I would have been more specific.

Comment: Well, there should be the initialisation messages from the HighPoint driver, which may actually help...

Comment: Wait a moment...this *could* be the cause of the problem!! Telling from my log files, __there is no driver__ used for this card, but the kernel uses its __generic__ driver for initializing that card instead! I'll now have to find a way how to load the correct HPT370 chipset driver by trying to `modprobe` the `pata_hpt37x` kernel module, "telling" the kernel not to access the card using its generic methods. However, modules with the `pata_` prefix are known to be experimental, hence there is a chance I will have to allow the use of these experimental modules...Whee, tricky stuff.

Comment: The bug you linked mentions that the drivers are experimental, but that hasn't been the case for a long time; they've been built by default in Debian since version 3.2.7-1, released in February 2012, and the kernel configuration doesn't link them to any experimental configuration flags.

Comment: @StephenKitt Sorry for the long delay, had no time for experiments, hence I had to remove the card in the meantime.-- Though I doubt the init msgs you requested will tell much, here they are: `pata_hpt37x: HPT370 using 33MHz bus clock | scsi host10: pata_hpt37x | scsi host11: pata_hpt37x`